# Error loading MySQLdb module Mountain Lion

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos, osx-lion

I know there is about 5 million questions on this, but I have tried for days the solutions posted and still cant figure it out. After running `python manage.py runserver` in terminal for Django, I get this message:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x143c290>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 23, in get_validation_errors
    from django.db import models, connection
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

I have already done the normal fixes including opening the `site.cfg` file within the pythonmysql converter and uncommenting `mysql_config = /usr/local/bin/mysql_config`. Does anyone have any last minute advice before I throw my computer against the wall?

Comment: Do you have the [`MySQLdb`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python) Python package installed? The Python interpreter that's running Django can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a good few days trying to get Django and MySQL to play nicely together the other week.  I finally managed to get it sorted with the help of this guide:

http://criticus-ua.tumblr.com/post/33260391135/setting-up-django-with-mysql-on-mac-os-x-lion

It's makes use of [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) which in my opinion is a great OSX package manager

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't really have the Python MySQLDB installed. You can check it from your Python Command Line by this,

```
import _mysql
```